# SQL Get All Results That Relate To All Keys

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-match-all

I've got a table that relates words to each other.

```
table_word_relationships
+-------------+-------------+
|   WORD_A    |  WORD_B     |
+-------------+-------------+
|   cat       |   dog       |
+-------------+-------------+
|   cat       |   rabbit    |
+-------------+-------------+
|   owl       |   cat       |
+-------------+-------------+
|   bird      |   dog       |
+-------------+-------------+
|   dog       |   banana    |
+-------------+-------------+
|   banana    |   cat       |
+-------------+-------------+
```

I need to run two types of queries on it.  One is easy.  Give me all the words that relate to the word "dog"

```
"SELECT * FROM table_word_relationships WHERE WORD_A = 'dog' OR WORD_B = 'dog'";
```

The result would be:

```
cat
bird
banana
```

The second one is the one I am having trouble with... 
I need to query for all words that have a relationship with ALL of the words in an array of words...

So, in English I would say "Give me all the words that have a relationship with the word "dog" and ALSO have a relationship with the word "CAT" 
The results would be:

```
banana
```

Because banana is the only word that relates to both keywords. What would be the proper type of SQL statement for this?

Comment: See this similar question with a lot (more than 10) ways to do just this: [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

Comment: The result of your first query will be two-column. And for the second one, i think you need to redesign your data model. you need one table for words and relationships. Then you query them with ease. Unless this is a homework i would highly recommend changing the data model.

Comment: @adam, I do have a separate table for the words, this is just an example I thought would be easier to understand.

Comment: @ypercube, thank you, looking at that now.

Comment: If you have all connections stored twice (meaning: `(dog, cat)` besides `(cat, dog)`), then most of your queries will be more simple.

Comment: @ypercube, so when I add the relationship I should just make two rows? then I could just query for column A instead of using OR column b?

Comment: Yes, your inserts would be inserting 2 rows. Then you won't need `OR` in the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query 1 should be:

```
SELECT word_b AS word
FROM table_word_relationships 
WHERE word_a = 'dog' 

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT word_a 
FROM table_word_relationships 
WHERE word_b = 'dog' ;
```

Query 2 gets quite complicated because you store every connection in one row only. One possible way:

```
SELECT
    dog.word
FROM
  ( SELECT word_b AS word
    FROM table_word_relationships 
    WHERE word_a = 'dog' 

    UNION DISTINCT

    SELECT word_a 
    FROM table_word_relationships 
    WHERE word_b = 'dog' 
  ) AS dog

  JOIN

  ( SELECT word_b AS word
    FROM table_word_relationships 
    WHERE word_a = 'cat' 

    UNION DISTINCT

    SELECT word_a 
    FROM table_word_relationships 
    WHERE word_b = 'cat' 
  ) AS cat

  ON cat.word = dog.word ;
```

---

Both your queries will much simpler if you are storing all connections in two rows, both `(cat, dog)` and `(dog, cat)`.

Query 1 then:

```
SELECT word_b AS word
FROM table_word_relationships 
WHERE word_a = 'dog' ;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT
    dog.word_b AS word
FROM 
    table_word_relationships AS dog
  JOIN 
    table_word_relationships AS cat
      ON cat.word_b = dog.word_b 
WHERE 
      dog.word_a = 'dog' 
  AND 
      cat.word_a = 'cat' ;
```

Comment: ypercube, I'm definitely going to heed your suggestion and add two rows per insert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `INTERSECT` command in SQL to find the intersection of several queries; i.e., returning what's common to all of them.

e.g.:

```
select field1 from table1 where id = 5
intersect
select field1 from table2 where id < 5
```

Comment: Interesting.  I'm running an intersect in PHP from queries for each keyword, I figured handling it all in SQL would be faster.  I'll look into this.

Comment: MySQL has not implemented `INTERSECT`.

Answer (score 0):

As you explained in your comment, you have 2 tables. I assumed the first table is called `words` with two columns: `id` and `word`. And the relationship table contains id and id2 foreign keys to words table.

Then you could try something like this:

```
select distinct word from words w
where 
(exists 
(select * from table_word_relationships r 
inner join word w2 on w2.id = r.id2 
inner join word w3 on w3.id = r.id 
where (w.id = r.id1 and w2.word = "CAT") or (w.id = r.id2 and w3.word = "CAT"))
and
(exists 
(select * from table_word_relationships r 
inner join word w2 on w2.id = r.id2 
inner join word w3 on w3.id = r.id 
where (w.id = r.id1 and w2.word = "DOG") or (w.id = r.id2 and w3.word = "DOG"))
```

(Not tested)